# opencv implementation with with custom layout (on SurfaceView)

Tags: android-layout, opencv, android-ndk

I have an openCV application program working, but need to add buttons etc. to the layout. So basically I want to display the opencv camera view on a surfaceView and the add the other stuff underneath.

I've been searching the internet and forums for a while, only seeing the guy with a opencv facial detection application also wanting to add a custom layout... no solution.

I am really desperate for a solution so would hugely appreciate help. For this purpose I used the OpenCV sample 3 application (as a simple example) and tried to bind to a surfaceview on a simple custom layout. I managed it in a normal Camera application, but struggling quite a bit with the opencv example.

So this is the code that I have for the Sample3Native.java, Sample3View.java and SampleViewBase.java (as in example) files respectively:

```
public class Sample3Native extends Activity {
private Sample3View mView;

private BaseLoaderCallback  mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("native_sample");

                // Create and set View
                mView = new Sample3View(mAppContext);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                //setContentView(mView);

                // Check native OpenCV camera
                mView.openCamera(); 
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

//constructor
public Sample3Native() {}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (null != mView)
        mView.releaseCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if((null != mView) && !mView.openCamera() ) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
        ad.setMessage("Fatal error: can't open camera!");  
        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            }  
        });  
        ad.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mOpenCVCallBack);
}
```

}

```
class Sample3View extends SampleViewBase {

private int mFrameSize;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private int[] mRGBA;

public Sample3View(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreviewStarted(int previewWidtd, int previewHeight) {
    mFrameSize = previewWidtd * previewHeight;
    mRGBA = new int[mFrameSize];
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidtd, previewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

@Override
protected void onPreviewStopped() {
    if(mBitmap != null) {
        mBitmap.recycle();
        mBitmap = null;
    }
    mRGBA = null;   
}

@Override
protected Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data) {
    int[] rgba = mRGBA;

    FindFeatures(getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight(), data, rgba);

    Bitmap bmp = mBitmap; 
    bmp.setPixels(rgba, 0, getFrameWidth(), 0, 0, getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight());
    return bmp;
}

public native void FindFeatures(int width, int height, byte yuv[], int[] rgba);
```

}

```
public abstract class SampleViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {

private Camera              mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder       mHolder;
private SurfaceView         mViewer;
private int                 mFrameWidth;
private int                 mFrameHeight;
private byte[]              mFrame;
private boolean             mThreadRun;
private byte[]              mBuffer;


public SampleViewBase(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mViewer = (SurfaceView)this.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    mHolder = mViewer.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public int getFrameWidth() {
    return mFrameWidth;
}

public int getFrameHeight() {
    return mFrameHeight;
}

public boolean openCamera() {
    releaseCamera();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    if(mCamera == null)
        return false;

    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            synchronized (SampleViewBase.this) {
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, mFrame, 0, data.length);
                SampleViewBase.this.notify(); 
            }
            camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
        }
    });
    return true;
}

public void releaseCamera() {
    mThreadRun = false;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
    onPreviewStopped();
}

public void setupCamera(SurfaceHolder holder,int width, int height) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mFrameWidth = width;
            mFrameHeight = height;

            // selecting optimal camera preview size
            {
                int  minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) {
                        mFrameWidth = size.width;
                        mFrameHeight = size.height;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
                    }
                }
            }

            params.setPreviewSize(getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight());

            List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
            {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
            }            

            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            /* Now allocate the buffer */
            params = mCamera.getParameters();
            int size = params.getPreviewSize().width * params.getPreviewSize().height;
            size  = size * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
            mBuffer = new byte[size];
            /* The buffer where the current frame will be copied */
            mFrame = new byte [size];
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                //mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            } catch (IOException e) {}

            /* Notify that the preview is about to be started and deliver preview size */
            onPreviewStarted(params.getPreviewSize().width, params.getPreviewSize().height);

            /* Now we can start a preview */
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder _holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    setupCamera(_holder,width, height);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    (new Thread(this)).start();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    releaseCamera();
}


//abstract functions used by child class
protected abstract Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data);
protected abstract void onPreviewStarted(int previewWidtd, int previewHeight);
protected abstract void onPreviewStopped();
//================================

public void run() {
    mThreadRun = true;
    while (mThreadRun) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                bmp = processFrame(mFrame);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (bmp != null) {
            Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - getFrameWidth()) / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - getFrameHeight()) / 2, null);
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know this must be a MAJOR drag to go through my code, but I really need the help. Or even if I could get a link to a working example of this type of implementation. Also, please just don't send me this link (it doesn't help me):[openCV in custom applications](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)

Comment: It is a major drag, and it hurts my eyes reading long post like this that are not properly formatted. Work on that! I see flying `}` characters, are they part of the code or not? If they are, they should be inside the code block.

Comment: Yeah, I also found it annoying that my } characters got excluded from the code blocks. Its my first time using stack overflow though, and thought you would get the idea. That's what the code block links did with the code. what's the manual way to include code. Anyway, have you combined an openCV project with a custom layout before, or any link to an example solution for this? I desperately need the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is my acitivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />

    <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:onClick="OKClicked"
        android:text="@string/OK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnOK"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And these code must be edited to MainActivity.java class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    if (mIsJavaCamera){
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
    }else{
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view);
    }
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.btnOK));
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.txtDisp));
    mOpenCvCameraView.addTouchables(views);
}

public void OKClicked(View view){
    TextView disp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDisp);
    disp.setText("OK Clicked");
}
```

This code is modified to OpenCV Tutorial 1.

You will see a button and a TextView over the surfaceview. When you click OK button TextView will show "OK Clicked". This is working for me on Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: I want to make Nativecameraview or Javacameraview be the background, but this way doesn;t work, it still overlay the button. Nothing is shown except the cameraview