# Button disabling and enabling functionality in opencv for android (runOnUiThread)

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, button

How to implement button disabling and enabling function in opencv for android. i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586705/opencv-implementation-with-with-custom-layout-on-surfaceview) post and was able get a button displayed on surfaceview.Now, if i try to disable this button or make it invisible using

```
btnOK.setEnabled(false); or btnOK.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

it will throw an error saying

> E/AndroidRuntime(24225):
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
public class Tutorial2Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2,OnTouchListener{

private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
private Mat                    mGray;
private Button            learnbutton;
private volatile Thread       btnthread;

private MenuItem               mItemPreviewLearn;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewFeatures;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewMatcher;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial2_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase)  findViewById(R.id.tutorial2_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.learnbutton));
    learnbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.learnbutton); 
    mOpenCvCameraView.addTouchables(views);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    mItemPreviewFeatures = menu.add("Find features");
    mItemPreviewLearn = menu.add("Learn object");
    mItemPreviewMatcher = menu.add("Find Match");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();
    mIntermediateMat.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    switch (viewMode) {

    case VIEW_MODE_LEARN:
        // make button invisible here
        //learnbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //learnbutton.setEnabled(false);
            //learnbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        runThread();
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        break;

    case VIEW_MODE_FEATURES:
       //enable the button here
      break;

    case VIEW_MODE_MATCHER:
     //enable the button here
        break;
    }

    return mRgba;
}




 private void runThread()
 {
btnthread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        learnbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    btnthread.start();

 }



}
```

Comment: do this in separate thread using "runonUIThread" android function

Comment: I tried using a separate runonUIThread, it is very slow, takes lot of time before the button is set visible. also if i switch between the menus it does not work i.e if the button is enabled or disabled it continues to do so in all three menu option. I have updated the problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `btnOK.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` is working fine.

Comment: Problem is the method onCameraFrame runs outside the UI thread and i have to do modifications there. i tried btnOK.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); outside this method i.e on oncreate  method , it worked completely fine